# No csv file is being created in output

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I am trying to extract emails from multiple excel files and get them appended in to a CSV file. The program was working for the last few days. But now it is not creating the CSV file in the output folder. I even tried to make one manually but it deletes the CSV file created manually as soon as i run the code.

here is my program

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd

# Regular expression pattern to match email addresses
email_pattern = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,7}\b'


# Function to extract email addresses from a string
def extract_emails(text):
    return re.findall(email_pattern, text)


# Function to extract emails from an Excel file
def extract_emails_from_excel(file_path):
    email_list = []
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
        for column in df.columns:
            for cell in df[column]:
                if isinstance(cell, str):
                    emails = extract_emails(cell)
                    email_list.extend(emails)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {file_path}: {e}")
    return email_list


# Specify the folder containing Excel files
folder_path = r'E:\1DW\Excel'

# Specify the path for the output CSV file
output_csv_file = r'C:\Users\HAL-2023\Desktop\Py_out\output_emails.csv'
# Ensure the output CSV file is empty or create it if it doesn't exist
if os.path.exists(output_csv_file):
    os.remove(output_csv_file)

# Loop through Excel files in the folder
for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx') or filename.endswith('.xls'):
        input_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        email_addresses = extract_emails_from_excel(input_file_path)

        # Append extracted email addresses to the CSV file
        if email_addresses:
            df = pd.DataFrame({'Email Addresses': email_addresses})
            df.to_csv(output_csv_file, mode='a', index=False, header=False)

print(f"Extracted email addresses written to {output_csv_file}")
```

Result

```
C:\Users\HAL-2023\Desktop\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\HAL-2023\Desktop\Python\email_from_excel.py 
C:\Users\HAL-2023\Desktop\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py:226: UserWarning: Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default
  warn("Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default")
Extracted email addresses written to C:\Users\HAL-2023\Desktop\Py_out\output_emails.csv

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But there is no file called "output_emails.csv" in that folder.

Comment: Your print statement will execute regardless of whether `df.to_csv` is executed. You need to indent it at the same level as the write call.

Comment: Your code deletes the CSV file if it exists when run so `output_csv_file` or the file `r'C:\Users\HAL-2023\Desktop\Py_out\output_emails.csv'` is always deleted regardless of whether you create a new file or not. Therefore ***I even tried to make one manually but it deletes the CSV file created manually as soon as i run the code*** would be expected,

Comment: Ok i see, so i manually created a file and commented out the part which deletes the file still nothing in that file. that file is empty.

Comment: Presumably no emails are extracted. Print the `email_addresses`  before the line `if email_addresses:` to see if there is anything in the list. Or alternatively print anything after the line `if email_addresses:` and before `df = pd.DataFrame({'Email Addresses': email_addresses})` to see if that part of the code is executed at all.

Comment: you are right, i put a print statement after the if email address and before the df =pd, it didn`t print anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the approach of deleting the `output_emails.csv` file at the beginning of the script and then trying to append to it. When you're iterating through multiple Excel files and trying to write emails to the CSV file, if one of those Excel files doesn't have any emails, it means you'll end up deleting the CSV and not recreating it, which can lead to the described behavior.

So instead of deleting the CSV file, you should check if it exists and append to it. If it doesn't exist, create it with a header.
You don't need to create a new DataFrame every time you want to append to the CSV file. Instead, you can use the CSV module to append the data.

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
import csv

# Regular expression pattern to match email addresses
email_pattern = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,7}\b'


# Function to extract email addresses from a string
def extract_emails(text):
    return re.findall(email_pattern, text)


# Function to extract emails from an Excel file
def extract_emails_from_excel(file_path):
    email_list = []
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
        for column in df.columns:
            for cell in df[column]:
                if isinstance(cell, str):
                    emails = extract_emails(cell)
                    email_list.extend(emails)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {file_path}: {e}")
    return email_list


# Specify the folder containing Excel files
folder_path = r'E:\1DW\Excel'

# Specify the path for the output CSV file
output_csv_file = r'C:\Users\HAL-2023\Desktop\Py_out\output_emails.csv'

# Check if the CSV file exists, if not create it with a header
if not os.path.exists(output_csv_file):
    with open(output_csv_file, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Email Addresses'])

# Loop through Excel files in the folder
for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx') or filename.endswith('.xls'):
        input_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        email_addresses = extract_emails_from_excel(input_file_path)

        # Append extracted email addresses to the CSV file
        if email_addresses:
            with open(output_csv_file, 'a', newline='') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerows([[email] for email in email_addresses])

print(f"Extracted email addresses written to {output_csv_file}")
```

Comment: I got it working. Thanks. The problem was indeed one of the excel files in the list which didn`t have any emails.